# How to implement file-substitution macro in bash?

Tags: bash, go, directive

I have a set of text files and a set of GoLang files. The GoLang files contain directives such as the following:

```
//go:embed hello.txt
var s string
```

I want to write a bash script which takes the above code and substitutes the following in its place:

```
var s string = "<contents of hello.txt>"
```

Specifically, I want to bash script to go through all GoLang source files and replace all `go:embed`/`string declaration` pairs with a string defined to be the contents of the file specified in the `embed` directive.

I'm wondering if there is an existing program which can be configured to do the above. Otherwise, I'm planning on writing the algorithm myself.

Further explaination:

I am trying to replicate GoLang's embed directive (https://tip.golang.org/pkg/embed/).

We are not yet on GoLang 1.16, so we cannot use this functionality, but we are replicating it as closely as possible so that moving over to the standard implementation is as painless as possible.

Comment: Is `hello.txt`'s content guaranteed to be in a format that can be directly substituted into a double-quoted string, or will it need escaping to be valid?

Comment: ...that said, note that requests for someone to give you "an existing program" are off-topic here; see #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. If you tried to write this yourself and then followed up with questions about specific problems you hit in the process, that would avoid the relevant issues -- I'd expect it to be a pretty quick bit of awk, though I also doubt it would be difficult to implement in Go either, since it's a language you already have expertise on, and are guaranteed to have dev tools for in your target environments. :)

Comment: I plan on using GoLang's raw-string literal so that it doesn't matter what the file contains, as long as it doesn't contain a single, predetermined sequence of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an attempt at solving your problem:

```
for i in file1 file2; do
   awk '/^\/\/go:embed /{f=$2;next}/^var/&&f{printf"%s = \"",$0;system("cat "f);print"\"";f=0;next}1' < "$i" > "$i.new"
done
```

The awk script prints all normal lines, only if it encounters the embed directive this line will be skipped (and the file name remembered in variable `f`).  A subsequent line starting with var will then be extended by the content of the file with the remembered name (using the system call "cat").

Beware, there are no error checks at all, no attempt to fix quotes and whatever.  So for practical use - unless the file contents you are about to embed are known to be good-natured - you probably have to take a more sophisticated approach.